# Unpack in a SSB

Tags: opengl, buffer, unpack

I use part of a SSB as a matrix 3D of linked lists. Each voxel of the matric is a uint that gives the location of the first element of the list.

Before each rendering, I need to re-init this matrix, but not the whole SSB. So I associated the part corresponding to the matrix with a texture 1D to be able to unpack a buffer inside it.

```
//Storage Shader buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &m_buffer);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, m_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 
    headerMatrixSizeInByte + linkedListSizeInByte, 
    NULL, 
    GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);

//Texture
glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_texture);
glTexBufferRange(
    GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 
    GL_R32UI, 
    m_buffer, 
    0, 
    headerMatrixSizeInByte);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);

//Unpack buffer
GLuint* clearData = new uchar[m_headerMatrixSizeInByte];
memset(clearData, 0xff, headerMatrixSizeInByte);
glGenBuffers(1, &m_clearBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_clearBuffer);
glBufferData(
    GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 
    headerMatrixSizeInByte, 
    clearData, 
    GL_STATIC_COPY);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
delete[] clearData;
```

So this is the initialization, now here is the clear attempt :

```
GLuint err;
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_clearBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_texture);
err = m_pFunctions->glGetError(); //no error
glTexSubImage1D(
    GL_TEXTURE_1D,
    0, 
    0,  
    m_textureSize, 
    GL_RED_INTEGER, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
    NULL);
err = m_pFunctions->glGetError(); //err GL_INVALID_VALUE
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
```

My questions are :

1. Is it possible to do what I'm attempting to ?
2. If yes, where did I screw up ?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly possible. What is the value of `m_textureSize`? There is the unknown issue of having an appropriate memory barrier in-place, but that *cannot* be to blame for the generation of `GL_INVALID_VALUE`. Nothing other than a potentially negative/uninitialized value of `m_textureSize` screams invalid to me.

Comment: `m_textureSize = 32770` (32*32*32 + 2). Could it be too big ?

Comment: Yes, that is larger than `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE` on *most* implementations I have worked with (the + 2 part is what really kills it). There ***is*** one type of 1D "texture" that can exceed the size of `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE`, a buffer texture (whose limit is defined by `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE`). But buffer textures cannot be filtered, you have to use `texelFetch (...)` to sample them. Moreover, you cannot even give them data using `glTex*Image1D (...)`, you have to use `glBuffer*Data (...)`, so I do not think they are what you want.

Comment: If I got the concept of the pixel unpack buffer right, the operation is extremely fast because the data is already stored in the GPU. `glBuffer*Dada()` can't be combined with PUBs so yeah, this is not what I want. However, if the limit is the size of the texture, I can easily find a hackish workaround and use texture2D or 3D and write over a small part of the linked list space. It will be overwritten in the compute shader anyway. I'll give a try later and keep you tuned. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Andon again who got half the answer. There is two problem in the code above :

1. `m_textureSize = 32770` which exceeds the limit in one dimension for many hardware. The easy workaround is to use a texture 2D. Since I don't care about the content after the linked list in the buffer, I can write whatever I want in it. In the next rendering call, it will be overwritten in the shaders.
2. When creating the texture, one function call was missing : `glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, width, height);`