# GLSL - Unpack in a SSB (V2)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

This question continue the subject here : [Unpack in a SSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747731/unpack-in-a-ssb)

With the previous setup, I found myself incapable to reset my SSB using the Pixel Unpack buffer.

My init function :

```
    //Storage Shader buffer
glGenBuffers(1, &m_buffer);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, m_buffer);
glBufferData(
    GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 
    1 * sizeof(uint), 
    NULL, 
    GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBufferBase(GL_SHADER_STORAGE_BUFFER, 0, 0);

//Texture
glGenTextures(1, &m_texture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_R32UI, 1, 1);
glTexBufferRange(
    GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 
    GL_R32UI, 
    m_buffer, 
    0, 
    1 * 1 * sizeof(GLuint));
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

//Unpack buffer
uint clearData = 5;
glGenBuffers(1, &m_clearBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_clearBuffer);
glBufferData(
    GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 
    1 * 1 * sizeof(GLuint), 
    &clearData, 
    GL_STATIC_COPY);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

My clearing function

```
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_clearBuffer);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture);
glTexSubImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    1,
    1,
    GL_RED_INTEGER, 
    GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 
    NULL);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The clear function doesn't work. If I try to access the value in the buffer with `glBufferSubData()`, BAADF00D is returned. If instead of an upack operation I use a simple `glBufferSubData()` It works.

How do I reset properly my SSB with the Pixel Unpack buffer ?

ANSWER :

The problem was binding my texture to `GL_TEXTURE_2D` instead of `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER`. However, there is an easier way to unpack inside my SSB :

```
m_pFunctions->glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, m_clearBuffer);
m_pFunctions->glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_buffer);
m_pFunctions->glCopyBufferSubData(
    GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER,
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    0,
    0,
    1);
m_pFunctions->glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
m_pFunctions->glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
```

This way I don't even need a texture.

Comment: Having that much code is actually a *good* thing, it gives us something to work with. Keep up that practice.

Comment: I'm not really sure what is going on, but this sequence in your init function does look a bit strange to me: `glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, m_texture);glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, ...);` You are repeatedly switching between `GL_TEXTURE_1D` and `GL_TEXTURE_2D` texture targets there.

Comment: @derhass mix between code of the old question and update of the new. I cleaned the code in the question.

Comment: Question purged of unecessary onformation. The problem comes back to an old one I thought I had solved. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I do not see anything bound to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` that would make `glTexBufferRange` a valid call. All I see is a 2D texture bound a few lines prior, but those two things are unrelated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [texture buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_buffer_object.txt) incorrectly. You are creating an ordinary 2D texture (including the actual storage) and then seem to try define a buffer of the storage. Your `glTexBufferRange()`  call will fail since you don't have any texture object bound to the `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` target.

But simply binding `m_texture` there will not make sense either. The point of TBOs is to make a buffer object available as a texture. You *can not* modify the TBO contents via the texture paths, `glTex(Sub)Image`/`glTexStorage` are not allowed for buffer textures, you have to use the buffer update mechanisms.

I don't see why you even try to do it via the texture path. Modyfing the underlying data storage is enough. And you can simply copy the contents of your PBO (or whatever kind of buffer you want to use) over to the buffer defining the storage for your TBO via [`glCopyBufferSubData()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glCopyBufferSubData.xhtml). Or, with modern GL, the most efficient approach might be using [`glClearBufferData`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glClearBufferData.xhtml) directly on the SSBO.

Comment: So does it make sense to bind m_texture to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` ?

Comment: @argum: no, it doesn't (I corrected my answer, since I forget the "not" in my sentence).

Comment: I didn't know about `glCopyBufferSubData()`. Exactly what I need. You mind if I had the correction to you answer before validation ?

Comment: @agrum: I just changed it to: "But simply binding m_texture there will **not** make sense either."

Comment: Could you provide a code example on how to create a TBO ? The documentation says I should use the same functions as usual (`glGenTextures` and `glBindTextures`) Except I should bind the texture to GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER ? Then it would be ok to call glTextBuffer ? (The final solution won't involve TBO in the end but I'm curious)

Comment: @agrum: yes. you create a texture object with `glGenTextures`, you bind it to `GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER` target, and the `glTexBuffer`/`glTexBufferRange` calls establish the buffer object as data store for the texture object.